# Need to change "a" to "e" or "o" depending if "a" position is even or odd using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Need "a"="e" if position is even and "a"="o" if position is odd. I'm new at pointers the program itself is easy to make put i don't understand how pointers work yet.

Heres the pointer.

```
void word(char *w[100])
{
    int n=0;
    while(*w[n]=='/0' && n<*w[n]){
        if(*w[n]=='a' && n%2==0)
            *w[n]='o';
        else if(*w[n]=='a' && n%2!=0)
            *w[n]='e';
    }
    n++;
}
```

When I did it without a pointer the program worked.

Heres the rest of the program.

```
void main(void)
{
    char pr[100];
    puts("Choose a word with letter a in it 'a' ");
    scanf("%s", &pr);
    word(pr);
    printf("The changed word is %s", pr);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make the pointer to work and where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What does your compiler say about the probable constraint violation (and definite undefined behavior) of passing a `char *` in place of a `char**`?

Comment: `char *w[100]` means an array of 100 pointers. But you're passing an array of 100 characters, not an array of pointers.

Comment: You also have a syntax error: `'/0'` should be `'\0'`.

Comment: I can't figure out what the heck you mean with `n < *w[n]`. Why would you compare the index to what's in the array?

Comment: OT: you don't need the `&` in `scanf("%s", &pr);`, `pr` is already (decays into) a pointer.

Comment: @Barmar `while (*w[n]=='\0' ...) `(or even `while (*w == '\0' ...)` ) does not make sense either

Comment: You want to raise the compiler's warning level and continue fixing the code until no more warnings are issued. The latter should not be achieved by wildly casting around, at least not as long you do not know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: `void word(char *w[100])` is the same as `void word(char *w[])` which is the same as `void word(char ** w)` which is not the same as `void word(char * w)`, which probably is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function, it actually passes a pointer to the first element. If the original array is `<type> <name>[<size>]`, the corresponding type of the argument is `<type>*`, not `<type>*[<size>]`. `char *w[100]` means an array of 100 pointers to characters, not an array of 100 characters as `pr` is declared in `main()`.

A pointer can be accessed using array notation: `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p+i)`. You don't use **both** array indexing and indirection (unless the array is an array of pointers, and you want to access what each element points to).

You also had your loop test wrong. You should loop as long as the current character of the string is **not** null, not while it **is** null, since the null character is at the end of the string. And the `n < *w[n]` test makes absolutely no sense at all.

So the function should be:

```
void word(char *w)
{
    int n=0;
    while(w[n] != '\0'){
        if(w[n]=='a' && n%2==0) {
            w[n]='o';
        } else if(w[n]=='a' && n%2!=0) {
            w[n]='e';
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

You can optionally declare a pointer argument using array notation, e.g.

```
void word(char w[])
```

But this is considered equivalent, it's still really a pointer that's passed. You can put an array size in there, but it's not used for anything.

Comment: The `if`...`else` can be replaced with `w[n] = 'oe'[n&1];`

Comment: That's true, but can != should.